# Is there a Recommended node.js equivalent for the Kohana Framework

Tags: javascript, node.js

The more I look at node.js the more, I'm really beginning to like it.  Everything is an object like ruby, but it isn't as different ( hippie like :P ).  Also you don't have to relearn all these syntaxes that are all globals `array_map`, `array_push`...

### So is there a similar equivalent of Kohana php for node.js?

I'm assuming node.js is ready for prime time if I wanted to set up a server and everything, or is there anything that I shoud be concerned/worried about.  I noticed nodejs.com demo is down, which is a bit concerning if I wanted to go live.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to get started with node.js which is freakin awesome if you ask me, you should look(comprehend) into:

- [npm](http://npmjs.org/)
- http://search.npmjs.org/
- [express](http://expressjs.com/)
- [socket.io](http://socket.io)
- [redis](http://redis.io)
- [node_redis](https://github.com/mranney/node_redis)
- [mongodb](http://www.mongodb.org/)
- [mongoose](https://github.com/LearnBoost/mongoose)
- [everyauth](https://github.com/bnoguchi/everyauth)

Like Jorge said express.js is a very popular framework to develop websites. Also if you master these topics I am sure you will really love node.js.

Comment: unless you know what your doing, I would avoid using redis and mongodb at the same time. It'll be hard to know exactly what data to store in which

Answer (score 4):

I think [express.js](http://expressjs.com/) is the most common framework for node.js as of now.

Comment: Please explain a bit about express ;)

Answer (score 1):

I am developing a framework inspired by Kohana at https://github.com/sadjow/falcon